# How to manage /var/mail/root file

Tags: filesystem, cron, mail

The size of `/var/mail/root` has been increasing as i am using lot of `cron` jobs and may cause memory shortage.

Is it wise to delete that file? How to manage this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should handle these kind of issues with `logrotate`, it is designed for these tasks specifically.

For example, to enable `logrotate` to rotate the file `/var/mail/root` if the size of the file becomes 10 MB, you can add a `logrotate` configuration file e.g. `/etc/logrotate.d/mailroot` with the content:

```
/var/mail/root {
        # Rotate if the size is >=10MB:
        size 10M  

        # Keep 5 rotated logs:
        rotate 5

        # Do not rotate if empty:
        notifempty 

        # Compresses rotated logs, default:
        compress  
}
```

You can define for the whole directory too using wildcard, `*`, so that it will be applicable to all files under it:

```
/var/mail/* {

....

}
```

As `logrotate` is run daily by `cron` (`anacron`), you do not need to add any `cron` entry if the configuration is put in `/etc/logroate.conf` or `/etc/logroate.d/*`. You can also define your own `crontab` entry if the configuration file resides elsewhere, you might also need a state file that will contain the current file rotation tatus.

Most importantly, check `man logroate` and `man 5 logroate.conf` to get more idea and options.

Comment: If anyone gets any permissions issues, you can add `su root mail` to tell logrotate which user and group to use with the config